# Componentdidmount: Get request and set state

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component and when it mounts, I want to get request and update state as shown below:

componentDidMount() {

```
    axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api")
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        Object.assign(this,{state:{isLoading: false}});
        this.setState({});
        console.log(this.state.isLoading);
    }).catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

I tried to use `this.setState()` as well as `Object.assign`, but when I console my `this.state.isLoading` it still shows true. Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be several reasons why you see `isLoading: true`. One of them being that `this.setState()` is asynchronous, so the `console.log` might run before the state is updated. You can check this by logging inside the callback function. This is the second parameter to `this.setState`, which is run when `this.setState` has completed.

Also, I would refrain from trying to assign state to this through Object-assignment and stick to `this.setState`. If you want to maintain the rest of your state while just changing `isLoading`, you can use the spread operator like this:

```js
this.setState({ ...this.state, isLoading: false}, () => console.log(this.state.isLoading))
```

Comment: you want me to replace this with what I had in the response function right? Also I noticed that basically each time componentdidmount runs it assumes the inital state for some reason. like if i log my state after `Object.assign` it is set to false but then it automatically goes true that means that it is assuming initial state values.

Comment: Glad to help!
(Inside the response function, correct.)
Using initial state, i.e. state from the constructor upon `componentDidMount` is intended behaviour, since that should preferably run only when it is initialized. If you're uncertain about the life cycles (which `componentDidMount` is part of), I find [React's own docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) on it pretty decent!